# FIND: Invalid Switch - not sure what is causing this error

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to find a specific substring within a string and when I use this code:

```
For /f "delims=" %%a in (Differences.log) do echo "%%a" | find /I "not admin" do if errorlevel 1 ( DiscordSendWebhook.exe -m "%%a" -n "n0t_k!p" do timeout /t 10 ) else ( Echo Player is not Admin ) do timeout /t 1
```

It throws this error.

```
FIND: Invalid Switch
```

I am using this code to step through a large text file with hundreds of lines that look along the lines of this:

```
[2022.09.21-03.33.41:653][917]Player Spicejunky#54619 entered movement mode Flying (player is not admin)
```

It takes the lines and uses the "DiscordSEndWebHook" to send the message into Discord.  I am trying to NOT send messages that contain "not admin".  This code works just fine when using it without the find statement, but it sends all messages:

```
For /f "delims=" %%a in (Differences.log) do DiscordSendWebhook.exe -m "%%a" -n "n0t_k!p" do timeout /t 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
For /f "delims=" %%a in (Differences.log) do (
 echo "%%a" | find /I "not admin" >nul
 if errorlevel 1 (
  DiscordSendWebhook.exe -m "%%a" -n "n0t_k!p" 
  timeout /t 10
 ) else ( Echo Player is not Admin )
 timeout /t 1
)
```

This will send any not-"not admin" lines to discord (then an **11**second timeout) and report `player is not admin` for "not admin" lines, then a **1**-second timeout.